# should jQuery files always be inside <head>?

Tags: jquery

Should the jquery related code external file (plugins etc.) always be in head of the html or it can be included somewhere in body as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can use a `SCRIPT` element either in `HEAD`, `BODY`, or wherever an *inline* element is allowed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362039/style-and-script-tags-in-html-body-why-not/1362192#1362192)

Additionally, many suggest to [put `SCRIPT` at the end of `BODY`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231005/are-there-any-performance-issues-in-having-a-large-number-of-script-tags-in-your/2231076#2231076) to improve loading of the document. You can also use tools like [Head JS](http://headjs.com/) to improve the loading even more.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily. Traditionally, the javascript code is to be put in `<head>` tags but you can put it in the `<body>` tag just as well.

As per [Yahoo ***performance*** article](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/), you should put your code at the end of the page just before `</body>` tag.

**Quoting:**

> Put Scripts at the Bottom
>
> The problem caused by scripts is that
>   they block parallel downloads. The
>   HTTP/1.1 specification suggests that
>   browsers download no more than two
>   components in parallel per hostname.
>   If you serve your images from multiple
>   hostnames, you can get more than two
>   downloads to occur in parallel. **While
>   a script is downloading, however, the
>   browser won't start any other
>   downloads, even on different
>   hostnames.**
>
> In some situations it's not easy to
>   move scripts to the bottom. If, for
>   example, the script uses
>   document.write to insert part of the
>   page's content, it can't be moved
>   lower in the page. There might also be
>   scoping issues. In many cases, there
>   are ways to workaround these
>   situations.
>
> An alternative suggestion that often
>   comes up is to use deferred scripts.
>   The DEFER attribute indicates that the
>   script does not contain
>   document.write, and is a clue to
>   browsers that they can continue
>   rendering. Unfortunately, Firefox
>   doesn't support the DEFER attribute.
>   In Internet Explorer, the script may
>   be deferred, but not as much as
>   desired. If a script can be deferred,
>   it can also be moved to the bottom of
>   the page. **That will make your web
>   pages load faster**.

---

If you are manipulating the DOM, you need to make sure javascript code is able to find the DOM elements by placing it at the appropriate place. You may also use `window.onload` event for that.

Answer (score 0):

Can be included but in `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>` tags

Look at this article:

- [Best practices for modern Javascript development](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/best-practices-for-modern-javascript-development)

  - Use the correct  tag
  - Keep your code in an external file
  - Don’t wrap code in HTML comments
  - Always declare your variables using var
  - Keep your code unobtrusive
  - Include your scripts at the bottom of your HTML files
  - Use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)
  - Don’t use document.write

Answer (score 0):

It does not need to be in the  and can be at the bottom of the page. For performance reasons it's better to load the jquery at the end.

Comment: However, if you do this, you mustn't execute any jQuery code before that

Answer (score 0):

jquery is javascript and so it should work in the body, however, a good coding standard for oop programmers like myself, is to put it in a different file if at all possible and only use the head for small things. I don't tend to use the body if i can help it as there is usually so much going on in there! What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: Actually im trying to build a basic template, where i have a general header. I call the header on all pages, but only on few pages some jquery plugins are needed, thats why i want to include the jquery related files only to those pages. any thoughts about it?

Comment: are you using php or asp.net? Any type of master page should have a place to add additional things to the head per page to make it most flexible for end use

Answer (score 0):

No they don't, but remember that anything inside the `<head>` section loads before elements in the `<body>` do.